# Extract the parts of an string (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I have a string like below.

```
$str = "ENGINE=InnoDB 
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
        COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
        COMMENT='Table comment'";
```

And I need to parse the key/value pairs from the string and combine them with the key/value pairs in the array below...

```
$arr = array("ENGINE" => "InnoDB",
             "DEFAULT CHARSET" => "utf8",
             "COLLATE" => "utf8_unicode_ci",
             "COMMENT" => "'Table comment'");
```

Here the sequence of the parts of the string can be different.

Example:

```
$str = "ENGINE=InnoDB
        COMMENT='Table comment'
        COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? You can use explode() to turn a string into an array.

Comment: How do you determine to break between InnoDB and DEFAULT, but not between DEFAULT and CHARSET?

Comment: You could try preg_replace with this regex: https://regex101.com/r/hQ5tD5/1

Comment: if you are trying to create a config file then I found using an array is the best method to go. As you can have a config file with a return array and by using include/require to store the array in a variable like `$config` and access like `$config["ENGINE"], $config["CHARSET"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and have PHP build your output from there in the format you'd like. Here's a working example in PHP. And the [regex statement](https://regex101.com/r/uF1wR4/1).

```
<?php
    $str = "ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT='Table comment' COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    preg_match_all("/([\w ]+)=(\w+|'(?:[^'\\\]|\\.)+')\s*/",$str,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $out = [];
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $out[$match[1]] = $match[2];
    }
    var_dump($out);
?>
```

And the result:

```
array(4) {
  ["ENGINE"]=>
  string(6) "InnoDB"
  ["COMMENT"]=>
  string(15) "'Table comment'"
  ["COLLATE"]=>
  string(15) "utf8_unicode_ci"
  ["DEFAULT CHARSET"]=>
  string(4) "utf8"
}
```

Explanation of regex

```
([\w ]+) // match one or more word characters (alpha+underscore+space)
= // match equals sign
  (
      \w+ // match any word character
   | // or
      ' // match one exact quote character
      (?:[^'\\]|\\.)+ // match any character including escaped quotes
      ' // match one exact quote character
   )
\s* // match any amount of whitespace until next match
```

Comment: @zedfoxus added an explanation for you

Comment: Very neat, @DavidBoskovic. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

String looks like `ini`-file. With [parse_ini_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php):

```
$str = "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT 
        CHARSET=utf8 
        COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
        COMMENT='Table comment'";

$data = parse_ini_string($str);
var_dump($data);

array(4) {
   ["ENGINE"]=>
   string(14) "InnoDB DEFAULT"
   ["CHARSET"]=>
   string(4) "utf8"
   ["COLLATE"]=>
   string(15) "utf8_unicode_ci"
   ["COMMENT"]=>
   string(13) "Table comment"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with space seperated keys like `DEFAULT CHARSET`

Comment: @David Boskovic did you try it, this case `space seperated keys like DEFAULT CHARSET`?) Of course, it works.

Comment: Ah, never mind, that's an issue with your example, not the code itself. I don't think the asker has the option to add new lines since the string appears to be directly from SQL. But, I like the approach in theory! I totally forgot that method exists in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verbose, inelegant way of parsing the data (with plenty of comment-explanation). This could be adapted for a differently structured string.

```
<?php

$str = "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Table comment'";
$keys = array('ENGINE', 'DEFAULT CHARSET', 'COLLATE', 'COMMENT');

$str_array = explode('=', $str); 
/* result of the above will be
[0] => ENGINE
[1] => InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET
[2] => utf8 COLLATE
[3] => utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT
[4] => 'Table comment' 
*/

$output = array();
$lastkey = '';

// loop through each split item
foreach ($str_array as $item) {

    // if the item is entirely one of the keys, just remember it as the last key
    if (in_array($item, $keys)) {
        $lastkey = $item;
        continue;
    }

    // check if item like InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET contains one of the keys
    // if item contains a key, the key will be returned
    // Otherwise, item will be returned
    $result = item_has_a_key($item, $keys);

    if ($result === $item) {
        // if the result is exactly the item, that means no key was found in the item
        // that means, it is the value of the previously found key
        $output[$lastkey] = $item;
    } else {    
        // if the result is not exactly the item, that means it contained one of the keys
        // strip out the key leaving only the value. Assign the value to previously found key
        $output[$lastkey] = trim(str_replace($result, '', $item));

        // remember the key that was found
        $lastkey = $result;
    }
}

print_r($output);
/*
Result:
[ENGINE] => InnoDB
[DEFAULT CHARSET] => utf8
[COLLATE] => utf8_unicode_ci
[COMMENT] => 'Table comment'
*/


// $item can be InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET
// $keys is the array of keys you have assigned (ENGINE, DEFAULT CHARSET etc.)
// if the item contains one of the keys, the key will be returned
// if the item contains no key, the item will be returned
function item_has_a_key($item, $keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (strpos($item, $key) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return $item;
}
?>
```

Comment: *blinks* This looks like you're trying to go in the direction of a hackish lexer. Lexer writing is pretty legit stuff. Check out this article if you're up for some late night fun: http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP

Comment: Thank you for sharing, @DavidBoskovic!